# Gradle - How can I execute bat file in new cmd window?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

An part of `build.gradle`:

```
task runCraftBukkit(type:Exec) {
    println "Starting CraftBukkit server..."
    commandLine = ['cmd', '/C', 'start', 'D:/Projects/WorkSpaces/WorldCleaner/devserver/start.bat'] // cmd /C start D:/Projects/WorkSpaces/WorldCleaner/devserver/start.bat
    workingDir = file('./devserver/')
}
jar.doLast {
    runCraftBukkit.execute()
}
```

Output:

```
15:13:54: Executing external task 'jar'...
Starting CraftBukkit server...
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:jar UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
...
```

But the command prompt window and *does not appear*.

*Question:*
What I do wrong?

Comment: try `start cmd /c batfile.bat`

Answer (score 5):

*Working* solution:

```
task runCraftBukkit(type:Exec) {
    doFirst {
        println "Starting CraftBukkit server..."
        workingDir = file('./devserver/')
        commandLine = ['cmd', '/C', 'start', 'start.bat']
        // cmd /C start D:/Projects/WorkSpaces/WorldCleaner/devserver/start.bat
    }
}
jar.finalizedBy runCraftBukkit
```

I spent a lot of time looking for errors. And the problem was not one :)

The main problem was that the task is not executed. Decision proved method `.finalizedBy`

And now:

```
...
:jar UP-TO-DATE
:runCraftBukkit
Starting CraftBukkit server...
...
```

That is exactly what i want to see :]

Comment: In the question `workingDir` and `commandLine` were probably in the right place, as they are configuration of the task. `println` on the other hand was executed during configuration, but was expected before execution - not to mention that it always prints, even if the task is NOT executed in the end. It's quite possible that even before the actual execution was after the JAR task (does it print something? try some `echo` in the batch file). `finalizedBy` is perhaps cleaner. See also: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html

Comment: This syntax doesn't work for build.gradle.kts files. What's the correct way to work with kotlin build files? Thanks.